# Ninject bind different implementations

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I've been using Ninject for a short time, and I'm trying to figure out how to do something that I've done in Unity with app.config/web.config entries.

I'm pretty sure this is simple, just haven't found the best way to implement it, and of course Ninject doesn't have the greatest documentation around.

I want to have different implementations for an interface, with no change in the code - the specific application knows which implementation to use.

For example, when I used Unity, I would have a live app and a unit test library, using different data libraries. So:

```
var repo = IoC.Get<IRepository>();
```

would return a `RealRepository` in my live app, and a `FakeRepository` in my unit tests. I would simply map the classes in my app.config or web.config.

In Ninject, since you define the mappings in the code, there doesn't seem to be a way to decide which implementations (or which module) you use, except in the code - but of course the whole purpose is I don't want to have to specifically state which implementation I want to use.

Is there a good way to do this? The only way I can think is to dynamically choose the NinjectModule implementation from the config file, but that just doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is sounds like you are missusing an IoC container as Service Locator. This gives you many problems. One of it is that testing is much more difficult. I suggest to do it right instead and do constructor injsction instead of service location.

This means instead of

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Do()
    {
        var repo = IoC.Get<IRepository>();
        ....
    }
}
```

You do

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IRepository repo;
    public MyClass(IRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

There is just one Get for the root of your application. Everything else is passed through constructors.

It makes testing really simple:

```
var testee = new MyClass(new Mock<IRepository>());
```

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth. :)  Good answer; I neglected to elaborate on the misuse implied by `IoC.Get<IRepository>()`.

Comment: You're right - when I was using Unity with everything in the config file, it let me avoid dependency injection altogether and just use it as a locator. You made me do a 180 in my head to think about using DI properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't your live app and your unit test libraries have different endpoints?  One is presumably a unit test project (nunit?) and the other is an application, (console, windows, or asp.net).

Each type of app should define their bindings independently, usually by defining separate modules (that you pass to the constructor of `StandardKernel`).  One set provides mappings for your real app, and another provides mappings for your unit tests.  The latter may or may not be necessary -- ideally the dependencies of a particular class you are testing should be easily mocked and passed in without using Ninject at all.  In practice, I've found many excuses where it was convenient to still use Ninject, in which case I create either a separate module or just rebind the kernel on the fly in the test itself.

Comment: In the latest version of Ninject I used, the idiomatic way was to create separate Module for separate projects. However, in unit tests you'll probably have a lot more because of the mixing and matching you need to do.

Comment: That should work well when you're calling something directly, or if I have test versions of every implementation. But suppose I have a business class which I don't mock, which uses Ninject to call the data repository. In my tests, I'd be making a call to the production implementation of the business class, but I want it to make a call to my test data repository. Since the business class doesn't know which environment it's in, it won't know to call the test repo.

Comment: I should clarify my comment. I'm assuming the business class creates a new kernel, and that kernel won't have the test mapping. If that assumption is wrong, then that might be my problem.

Comment: @Joe, yes, that is wrong way to go about it -- every application should have only *one* instance of a kernel.  This is why there is an [extension for ASP.NET/MVC](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc), as that describes one type of application endpoint.  There is [another for WCF](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.common) as technically web services are another application endpoint.  And so on.  The point being, each type defines only one instance of `Kernel`.  (Out of curiosity, what type of app houses the "business class"?)

Comment: Thanks - that makes a lot of sense to make the kernel global in the application. Regarding the business class, I didn't describe it well. It's just a normal tiered approach, for example: my front end app (or unit test) calls `myProductManager.GetProduct(id)`. The ProductManager implementation in turn calls `myProductRepo.GetProductFromDB(id)`, then does whatever it needs to, and returns something back to the caller. I wanted to create a test IProductRepo but not a test IProductManager, and it wasn't working when I had a kernel defined in ProductManager.